# mergesort tree implementation in python

Tags: python

```
n=4
arr=[1,2,3,4]
tree=[[] for i in range(2*n-1)]
def build_tree(idx,l,r):
    if l==r:
        tree[idx].append(arr[l])
    else:
        mid=(l+r)//2
        build_tree(2*idx,l,mid)
        build_tree(2*idx+1,mid+1,r)
        tree[idx]=merge(tree[2*idx],tree[2*idx+1])


def merge(left,right):
    myList=[]
    i=0
    j=0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:

            myList.append(left[i])

            i += 1
        else:
            myList.append(right[j])
            j += 1



    while i < len(left):
        myList.append(left[i])
        i += 1


    while j < len(right):
        myList.append(right[j])
        j += 1

    return myList


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_tree(0,0,n-1)
    print(tree)
```

I am implementing merge sort tree in python https://discuss.codechef.com/t/merge-sort-tree-tutorial/14277.   .When I print the tree I am getting following output

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [3], [4], [], [], []] which is wrong.

but few values such as [1] and [2] are missing .I do not where I am wrong .There is no python implementation available on the internet for merge sort tree.Please help me to correct  it or if possible please provide another implementation in python.

Answer (score 0):

The index math you're doing in your recursive step is wrong, so only the right half of the tree appears. The issue has to do with zero-indexing. If the root is zero, the left branch needs to be `1` and the right branch `2`. Your code produces `0` and `1`, so half the tree disappears.

Try:

```
else:
    mid=(l+r)//2
    build_tree(2*idx+1,l,mid)          # +1 for idx argument here
    build_tree(2*idx+2,mid+1,r)        # +2 instead of +1 here
    tree[idx]=merge(tree[2*idx+1],tree[2*idx+2])  # also update the indexes used here
```

Comment: thankyou sir ,I never thought of this I should have used 2*idx+1 and 2*idx+2.Thanks again

Comment: lower_bound(tree[cur].begin(),tree[cur].end(),K)-tree[cur].begin();   I want to implement similar to this. how to do it in python I do not know c++.Could you please tell me how to do it.